# Which flag to add to chrome to not see c:/fakepath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, file-upload

**I know this is a security feature, how do I turn it off?**

As the title says, I am looking for a flag or something to add to chrome to get the actual full file path of a file uploaded or seen (uploading a directory). It works fine in IE because there is a setting I can set to allow local file access.

I can get the relative path which doesn't help at all. I have tried using chrome's flag --allow-file-access-from-files but it doesn't work. I think that only works if you want access to save something to the file system. Or maybe I am using it wrong.

This is for local PERSONAL use only - I am making something for myself. Currently I am using the temporary path to display the images but I would much rather just want to access the files on their own.

Here is a basic version of the code:
HTML:

```
<input type="file">
<br />
<div></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').change(function(){
        $('div').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Here is a JSfiddle of a small example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Chris/cL8dfopc/

jsfiddle of more code using indexeddb and temporary path - use chrome to open this:
https://jsfiddle.net/Chris/0a9ja8t9/1/

**What do I want?**

I want to get access to the full path to the file that was selected in the input like in Internet Explorer but on Chrome. I do not mind adding flags or altering the registry to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specified in HTML5: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-value-filename

There's no flag or anything.